# Itext PdfAction link is not working in firefox and chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, pdf, itext

I am using pdfAction in my pdf to generate link to remote pages.Everything is working fine when i am opening the pdf in acorbat and link is working fine but when i am opening pdf in chrome or firefox nothing happens on clicking on links.It is working fine in Internet explorer.

Can anyone suggest the solution ?

Thanks

Comment: It's a probably a viewer problem. Replace the viewer used by your browser with the Adobe Reader plug-in.

Comment: @Bruno can you please tell me how can i do that ?

Comment: That depends on the browser. Each user needs to configure his own browser. You can't enforce the use of a specific PDF viewer from the server.

Comment: @Bruno if i do so then when i am clicking on a link in html page which targets to a pdf to particular page, pdf always gets opened from the first page instead of mentioned page no.It only works when browser opens the pdf in it's own viewer.

Comment: You say: it works in MSIE / Adobe Reader's plug-in. This tells me that the PDF is created correctly. When you say: it doesn't work as expected in Chrome's PDF Viewer, nor in Firefox's pdf.js, then there's probably a problem with those viewers. In that case: why try fixing the problem at the iText level (where there is no problem, so there's nothing to fix) instead of fixing the problem where it happens (in the browser)?

Comment: i think you are right.

Answer (score 0):

There is no change at iText level. Add Acrobat Plugin Extension in google Chrome or Firefox. Set to open pdf in Acrobat view. Set action with total url path : submit1.setAction(PdfAction.createSubmitForm(http://localhost:9090/example/example", null, 0)); submit action will work fine.